# UMLS MetamorphoSys: "No suitable BrowsableInputStream founds"

Tags: windows-7, metamorphosys

I am trying to open a subset in UMLS MetamorphoSys:

[image]

[image]

But I get the error:

[image]

Why?

I use the UMLS 2015AA Release with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a few years late but this could be of use to someone. This issue can be resolved by File -> Open Subset and Under 'Directory', 'Browse' to the folder which was your destination when you had installed MetamorphoSys (say mmsys) mmsys\2015AB\META . This should take care of the issue. I haven't tried MySQL yet but it basically needs to know where you have installed the Thesaurus which in the error is the 'BrowsableInputStream'.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this answer?